# How to fix MongoDB documents being just id and __v

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I try to add a post to the database the JSON Body is perfectly fine, but when I retrieve these it only shows id and __v (versionKey)

I've tried using body-parser in different ways, such as...

```
app.use('bodyParser.json()')

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
```

The last two included in the app.post method.

This is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;
const postRoutes = express.Router();

let Post = require('./post.model');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.use(cors());
app.use('/', express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);


mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mern-blog-test", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Succesfully established connection to MongoDB Database');
})

postRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    Post.find(function (err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(posts);
        }
    });
});


postRoutes.route(':id').get(function(req,res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Post.findById(id, function(err, post) {
        res.json(post);
    });
});

// todoRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
//     let todo = new Todo(req.body);
//     todo.save()
//         .then(todo => {
//             res.status(200).json({ 'todo': 'todo added successfully' });
//         })
//         .catch(err => {
//             res.status(400).send('adding new todo failed');
//         });
// });

app.get('/create', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/add.html');
})

app.post('/makepost', urlencodedParser, function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    let post = new Post(req.body);
    post.save()
        .then(todo => {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/add.html')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new post failed!');
        });
});
```

This is my form

```
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select name="category">
            <option>Coding</option>
            <option>Music</option>
            <option>Books</option>
            <option>Other Stuff</option>
        </select>
        <label for="content">Content</label>
        <input type="text" name="content">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

And my post.model.js

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Post = new Schema({
    post_title: {
        type: String
    },
    post_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    post_shortdesc: {
        type: String
    },
    post_content: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', Post);
```

I expect the output to be...

```
[{"_id":"5d76a7e78b55cd3309b91ecf", "title": "blah", category: "blah", "content": "blah", "__v":0}]
```

But it is...

```
[{"_id":"5d76a7e78b55cd3309b91ecf","__v":0}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry figured it out myself. Form was outputting fields that weren't in the model. Changed form to...

```
<form id="add-form" method="POST" action="/makepost">
        <label for="post_title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="post_title">
        <!-- <label for="post_category">Category</label>
        <select name="post_category">
            <option>Coding</option>
            <option>Music</option>
            <option>Books</option>
            <option>Other Stuff</option>
        </select> -->
        <label for="post_date">Content</label>
        <input type="date" name="post_date">
        <label for="post_content">Content</label>
        <input type="text" name="post_content">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Basically just changed the names of input fields to match the model.